# How can I run a Python subprocess command and prefix the output with a timestamp?

Tags: python, unix, subprocess, popen

I have a Python script that runs some subprocess commands on a Unix machine. The commands are relatively arbitrary. One example would be

`docker build .`

which ends up looking like

`subprocess.Popen(['docker', 'build', '.'])`

I want to prepend each line of output from the arbitrary command to contain a timestamp. From some hunting around the best answer i could find on SO was to pipe to this: `| while IFS= read -r line; do printf '[%s] %s\n' "$(date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')" "$line"; done`

however that doesn't seem to work with subprocess. Is there a better way?

Comment: Maybe use `ts`, see https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-use-the-ts-command-to-add-timestamps-to-output-686c92ef6124

Comment: to use `|` you may need to run with `shell=True` because `pipeing` is part of `bash.`, WIthout `shell=True` you may need to catch output (`stdout`) and send to another `subprocess` with `while`. But `while` is also part of `bash` and it may need `shell=True`. But if you get output then you can use `print()` in Python to display `timestamp`

Comment: you can also create bash script with `your command | while ...` and run this script in `subprocess`

Comment: Note that most commands will buffer their output when writing to a pipe. Which means you can't really determine when a line was written because it could be a long time before the line is flushed so you can read it. You need to use a pseudo-tty (pty) for the stdout and stderr streams of the process or a CLI option provided by the program to disable buffering of its output.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this using `pexpect` to prepend the timestamp (or do whatever logging can do) for each line of output:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import logging
import pexpect


logging.basicConfig(filename='ts.log', encoding='utf-8', format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s', level=logging.DEBUG)


def run(cmd):
    logging.info(cmd)
    p = pexpect.spawn(cmd, encoding="utf-8")
    while l := p.readline():
        logging.info(l.strip())

run("ls -l")
```